# JS - How to know when browser back or forward button is pressed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to know whether an user clicked on the back button of the browser of on the forward button, because I show and hide a DIV based on the hashtag ID in the address bar.

My code:

```
    window.onhashchange = function() {      
        var times;
        if (location.hash.length > 0) {        
            times = parseInt(location.hash.replace('#',''),10);   

            //window.history.back();
            console.log(times);

            var timesone = times + 1;
            var timesminone = times - 1;
            console.log(window.hashVar);
            $('#wizard-frame-' + timesone).hide('fade');
            $('.active-step').removeClass('active-step');
            $('#step-' + times).addClass('active-step');
            $('#wizard-frame-' + times).show('fade');

        } else {
            times = 0;
        }

    }
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't distinguish between the back and forward button so it hides the wrong DIV when forwarding

Comment: There is an Eventhandler onpopstate [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onpopstate) Maybe it helps you out :)

Comment: I looked into that document already, but that didn't help me to distinguish between the back and forward button (at least, I don't know how)

Comment: @user1857116 you can't know whether the back or forward button was clicked. Indeed the user could move more than 1 place forward or backwards each time. You will have to store some state in the history stack which will be part of the event arguments when the popstate event is fired. You might wish to read more about the [HistoryAPI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API).